# PHP while loop issue with associative array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop, associative

I have two while loops populating associative arrays -- I can run one at a time (ie commenting the other out) however, when I run both at the same time I receive a server error. Despite the queries not querying the same set of data I've still tried adding a pointer reset with no luck. Here are the two loops:

```
$thecurrent = array();
$getusers = "SELECT score, uid, like_id FROM wetique_scores GROUP BY like_id;";
$gotusers = mysql_query($getusers,$con);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($gotusers))
{
    $score = $row['score'];
    $userid = $row['uid'];
    $likeid = $row['like_id'];
    $comboid = $userid.$likeid;
    $thecurrent[$comboid] = $score;
}
```

// 2. calculate new score from db and create array $new

```
$new = array();
$getusers2 = "SELECT like_id, sum(friend_rating), uid from likes l, friendships f WHERE l.friend_id = f.friend_id GROUP BY l.like_id;";
$gotusers2 = mysql_query($getusers2,$con);
while ($rowb = mysql_fetch_array($gotusers2))
{
    $scoreb = $rowb['sum(friend_rating)'];
    $useridb = $rowb['uid'];
    $likeidb = $rowb['like_id'];
    $comboidb = $useridb.$likeidb;
    $new[$comboidb] = $scoreb;   
}
```

Comment: What does the server error say?

Comment: `from l,` in second query. Is this a typo or table name is `l`?

Comment: The server says: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: from l was a typo, updated the code snippit

Comment: I suggest you give an alias to `sum(friend_rating)` such as `sum(friend_rating) AS sum`, so you can do `$rowb['sum']`.

Comment: good call...made that change, but upon looking at php_logs I'm seeing this error" PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 90 bytes)". As I mentioned below, each array only has about 100k rows with the $key and $value being fewer than 20 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no `'l_id'` in selected fields of your queries, so `$rowb['l_id']` or `$row['l_id']` will generate Notice.
2. `from l, fips f` this is typo i hope?
3. Your `GROUP BY l_id` isn't clear. All rows with same `l_id` has same `score, uid, like_id`? Very strange.
4. Use `mysql_free_result` after each cycle https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-free-result.php

Comment: Please excuse those typos, they've been fixed. Neither query or loop will generate a typo on it's own (with the other commented out)...it's just when running one loop after the other.

Comment: Look ento error_logs for detailed error description. And remove `;` from the end of the queries - they are useless here :)

Comment: in php_logs I'm seeing this error: "PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8 bytes)". Very weird because the array's are only about 100k rows each.

Comment: And still i don't like your first query - it's meaningless, why you use `group by` there?

Comment: preventing duplicates, and no doubt that can be optimized. Thoughts on the "Fatal error"? What can cause such a large memory leak like this? Anything in the loop pop out?

Comment: There's no leaks. Look 33554432bytes/200000rows = only 168 bytes per row. Of course it's not enough.

Comment: Use `mysql_free_result` and maybe use select data by chunks (with LIMIT)

Comment: thanks for your help.Here's the revised initial loop (the other is commented out) (still getting the memory error)...any other ideas? $thecurrent = array();
$getusers = "SELECT score, uid, like_id FROM scores LIMIT 10000;";
$gotusers = mysql_query($getusers,$con);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($gotusers))
{
 $score = $row['score'];
 $userid = $row['uid'];
 $likeid = $row['like_id'];
 $comboid = $userid.$likeid;
 $thecurrent[$comboid] = $score;

}

mysql_free_result($getusers);